# ckeditor doesnot sends data in first attempt, initial value is not updated?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ckeditor

Hello i am using ckeditor for a textarea in my website and it does not gets updated when i add data in the textarea , what i mean is

> **When i add data in ckeditor textarea and submits the form i get receive the previous value not new, in first submit i always get blank
>   data as the initial state of textarea is always empty. **

i dont know if i can explain myself better ir not but when i submit the form i get nothing in 1st submit, get the data in second submit same form without any refresh.

> after my resurch i get to know that while submiting the form through
>   AJAX i might have to update the value automatically inot the textarea
>   so that i can be passed.

i have no idea after spending 3 hrs here.

here is the code

```
<script src="https://cdn.ckeditor.com/ckeditor5/15.0.0/classic/ckeditor.js"></script>

<form class="form-horizontal form-label-left row" onsubmit="return ajaxsubmitform('something');">
<textarea name="desc" class="form-control" placeholder="Describe the papers" id='richtext' style="height: 200px;"><?=$theallamesages['up_desc']?></textarea>

</form>

<script>
                ClassicEditor
.create( document.querySelector( '#richtext' ) )
.then( editor => {
    console.log( editor );
} )
.catch( error => {
    console.error( error );
} );
            </script>
```